# Specify IP + guest hostname on a virtual machine (without booting it)

Tags: virtualization, ip, dynamic

My question is simple but I am not sure if it is possible :

Is there a way to specify a custom IP address AND a different hostname before I boot a virtual machine from VMWare Workstation ?  (Win 7 or Win XP guest OS)

Example :

- Virtual Machine #1 is running Windows XP

  1. Run a copy of virtual machine #1 with ip 192.168.0.10 and with hostname PC01
  2. Run a second copy of virtual machine #1 with ip 192.168.0.60 and with hostname PC28

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this in VCenter. Not sure about Workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not the IP address is stored in the OS only VMWare doesn't provide this. The only network-related stuff you'll find stored in the *.vmx file is the Mac address.

Good luck

Comment: Your question was also about hostname this is also only stored in the OS en not he config. (missed that the first time)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can either 1) disconnect the network adapters, boot with VMWare Console, and re-assign; 2) create a script that can be invoked by bootloader or in early OS boot process that can rewrite the values of `hostname` and `/etc/sysconfig/network`.